# Combobox jquery find selected val

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms

Hi guys i have a combobox with jquery - but i cant make the second one populated when the first select coming selected alredy. im try to get the value without change the select.

```
<form>
    <select name="tipo" id="Tipo_Id" class="buscaTiposVeiculos">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">teste1</option>
        <option value="2">teste2</option>
        <option value="3">teste3</option>
        <option value="4">teste4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="marca" class="recebeMarcas">
        <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**jquery**

```
$('select.buscaTiposVeiculos').change(function () {
     $("select.recebeMarcas").html('<option value="">Carregando...</option>');

     // var opt = $("select.buscaTiposVeiculos"); tried like this
     // var val = $(this).val(); tried like this
     // var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val(); not works
     $('select.recebeMarcas >option').remove();
     $.post('/inc/geraCidades.php', {
         tipov: $(this).val(),
         tipo: "tipo"
     }, function (data) {

         $('select.recebeMarcas').html('<option value="">Selecione a Marca</option>' + data);
     });
 });
```

Comment: code you have is valid (except you are adding/removing options too much before $.post)... not sure what you want or what problem is

Comment: if is invalid why this works if i manually select a option?

Comment: no..I said code IS valid  ... but not sure what problem you are having

Comment: if i choose a option on the first select the second select is populated fine.. but the first select starts with the value ="1" alredy selected but this only works if i change, and i tried alot options and dont works.. like this jQuery('select.buscaTiposVeiculos').live('change', function() { etc etc

Comment: OK...so you want second to populate on page load..without user make change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger change event on page load and populate second select automatically. Some commented code can be removed

```
/* create the change handler  use ID is better selector for efficiancy*/
$('#Tipo_Id').change(function() {                                              
     /* this populates second select with one option*/
    $("select.recebeMarcas").html('<option value="">Carregando...</option>');                                          

   /* this removes option populated in line above*/
    $('select.recebeMarcas >option').remove();


    $.post('/inc/geraCidades.php', {tipov: $(this).val(), tipo : "tipo"}, function(data) {

        $('select.recebeMarcas').html('<option value="">Selecione a Marca</option>'+data);
    });

    /* trigger the change event on page load*/
}).change();
```

Comment: the question was not very understandable or you would have had answers a long time ago...glad it worked

Answer (score 1):

your selected value is

```
$("#Tipo_Id option:selected").val();
```